# Pennylane Spectral gap for Molecules

Tags: pennylane, chemistry

Pennylane's dataset has a lot of systems, including Quantum Chemistry molecules. Can I extract the spectral gap of the molecule from the dataset (assuming it contains the number). In the case that this value is not readily available, is there a pennylane tutorial to find this?

I do not imagine it would be feasible to run simulation on my computer or even google colab to calculate the spectral gap of such large molecules. Is there any other repository/database from where we can get the spectral gap of popular molecules mentioned in pennylane?